# Is there any way to load an assembly compiled in VS2010 in VS2005?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-2.0, .net-4.0

We have a function in a VS2005 project that loads assembles and get type information  from them . It does not instantiate these types though. We tried to load some assembles that are compiled in 2010, but keep getting the following exception.

"Could not load file or assembly '2010ClassLibrary' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: you could try a reflection-only load, but it's a stretch that it would be able to loading CLR4-targeted assemblies

Comment: can you upgrade the VS2005 project to .net 4? :)

Comment: If you don't own the assemblies then you need to ask the ones who made them for a .Net 2.0 version if possible (as long as you are using VS2005 yourself). You could look at the Express versions of VS2010 if you need a free version to work with.

Comment: Assuming that it is not a visual component (eg. Business Logic) you could proxy it out by creating a VS 2010 based windows service project and host your 2010 asssebly there exposing it via WCF.

HTH

Answer (score 5):

If you are not using any .Net 4 features in your code in the VS2010 solution, then set your target for the solution to be .Net 2.0 instead. This will allow you to reference it in VS2005. .Net 3.5 can be used in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

you could run the app under .net 4 and then the code to load the assembly should be fine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4kkd0k5.aspx